# Is quadrupole contribution to gravitational potential the sum of the contribution of all $m$ values?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, multipole-expansion

Many of the sources I find on multipole expansions seem to be about electric potential and involve matrices. However, in my classical mechanics class we have not used matrices for multipole expansions yet, so I have not been able to answer my question with them. We were given this formula for the multipole moments of gravitational potential: $q_{lm} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2l + 1}}\int dV \rho r^l Y_{lm}^\ast(\theta,\phi)$.

The concepts of the monopole moment, dipole moment, quadrupole moment, etc. were introduced to us in the context of an azimuthally symmetric mass distribution, so we knew $m = 0$. To find the quadrupole moment for example, we would have found $q_{20}$. But now I am encountering questions that ask for the quadrupole moment of the gravitational potential of non azimuthally symmetric masses.

Do I add up the $q_{2m}$ for each possible m ranging from $-2$ to $2$? If not, how do I find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quadrupole moment is a *tensor*, i.e., it's not the sum of $q_{2,m}$ over all $m$, it's just $q_{2,m}$, thought of as a spherical tensor of rank-2 with components $q_{2,m}$. Equivalently, in Cartesian coordinates, it takes the form of a symmetric, traceless matrix, which has five independent entries $Q_{xx}$, $Q_{yy}$, $Q_{xy}$, $Q_{xz}$, and $Q_{yz}$. The $q_{2,m}$'s can be written as linear combinations of the $Q_{ij}$'s and vice-versa.

This is analogous to how the dipole moment is a *vector* with three components $D_x$, $D_y$, and $D_z$, corresponding to three orthogonal directions $x$, $y$, $z$, in space.  Equivalently, it's a spherical tensor of rank 1 with components $d_{1,m}$, where $m=-1,0,1$.

Only the monopole moment is a scalar.